# goodluckdog.space removal from FF in RHEL

Tags: firefox, redhat-enterprise-linux, adware

ALL,

Most of the instructions, if not all, on the Web (Google) is for Windows, but I need a way to do that in RHEL on FF.

I did search the FF "Add-On" menu, but it is empty - nothing is there.

I did check the "Options"/"Prefedrences" menu, but again - nothing is there.

And I still am redirecting to this stupid site (Adware).

Any suggestions?

TIA!!

Comment: Does the problem present when you use an alternative browser? Does it occur when you use an alternative PC? (I'm thinking the problem could be cached content or a DNS/router infection)

Comment: Relatedly, have you flushed your caches, and dies it occur when doing private browsing?